# I know how to find a midpoint,but in this code i am not sure how will this calculate midpoint if we add to it value

Tags: java, arrays

```
private int mid(int left, int right) {
    if (left <= right)
        return (right - left) / 2 + left;
    else
        return (left - right) / 2 + right;
}
```

what is the purpose of adding left or right to the result if we are looking for midpoint

Comment: Why don't you omit `left`and `right`, try to find the midpoint betwenn, let's say, 20 and 30, and see what happens?

Comment: since 20<30 then the result = 25 is the midpoint, 
but according to the return function the result is going to be 25+20=45 
i don't if I'm right with that

Comment: How would **you** find the midpoint if you calculated it by hand? Can you write code that does it the same way? (Hint: you can do it with a single line of code rather than an `if...else` statement.) From there I suggest comparing the differences.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice's approach is a common practice and should always be used when you need to calculate a value.  (and in programming in general)

Comment: on a side note, that should probably be a `static` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's analyze this code piece by piece:

```
if (left <= right)
```

This is if the `left` value is actually to the left of the `right` value.  If it is, it will treat it as such.

```
return (right - left) / 2 + left;
```

`(right - left)` is the length of the line; divide it by two and you get half the distance.  Add that to the left value and you have traveled rightwards for half of the length of the line.

```
else
    return (left - right) / 2 + right;
```

This code accounts for the fact that `left` might actually be greater than `right`, which means that it is actually on the right.  If it is, than the roles of `right` and `left` are switched in the next line.

Comment: So, you mean what it is trying to do is which way should we go if we are looking for a value.

Comment: @moalbait Yes.  Even though the parameters are called `left` and `right`, someone might put a higher value in `left` than in `right`, in which case right will be on the left and left will be on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Another kind of analysis:

```
mid = (left - right)/2 + right 
    = left/2 - right/2 + right 
    = left/2 + right/2 
    = (left + right)/2
```

The case where `left <= right` is left as an exercise.